# Pass props inside function on firebase.utils.js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, async-await, react-hooks

I have a weird question, but I really cannot get it fixed and I have been stumbling upon it for days now.

Here I have a functional component - SignUp:

```
const SignUp = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    displayName: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    confirmPassword: "",
  });

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const { displayName, email, password, confirmPassword } = user;

    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
      alert("Passwords don't match");
      return;
    }

    try {
      const { newUser } = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email,
        password
      );

      console.log('SignUp displayName: ', displayName);

      await createUserProfileDocument(newUser, displayName);

      setUser({
        displayName: "",
        email: "",
        password: "",
        confirmPassword: "",
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setUser({ ...user, [name]: value });
  };

  return (
    // Form with displayName, email, password, confirmPassword inputs
  );
};
```

And this is the 'createUserProfileDocument' function from the firebase.utils:

```
export const createUserProfileDocument = async (userAuth, additionalData) => {
    if (!userAuth) return;

    const userRef = firestore.doc(`users/${userAuth.uid}`);

    // const snapShot = await userRef.get();

    console.log('additionalData: ', additionalData);

    console.log('userAuth: ', userAuth);

    // if (!snapShot.exists) {
    //     const { displayName, email } = userAuth;
    //     const createdAt = new Date();
    //     try {
    //         await userRef.set({
    //             displayName,
    //             email,
    //             createdAt,
    //             ...additionalData
    //         });
    //     } catch (err) {
    //         console.log('error creating user', err.message);
    //     }
    // }

    return userRef;
};
```

Problem on this code, is that when I submit the form, it triggers the handleSubmit which calls the createUserProfileDocument function.. At that point, it gets the userAuth object properly, but it doesn't get any 'additionalData' prop, displaying undefined instead..

What can be the reason for that? I can confirm both the form and handleChange work properly, updating the user hook state with the inserted values

The console.log I added on the SignUp component (inside handleSubmit) displays the displayName correctly; On the other hand, the console.logs inside the firebase.utils, display the userAuth but instead of getting those additionalData (which in this case is the displayName), it gets undefined

Here what I get from the console.logs:
[image: Console.logs]

On userAuth I still don't get any displayName but can retrieve the email:
[image: userAuth displayed on console.log]

This are the user properties that gets saved after filling the form:
[image: User state]

I really don't get what I'm doing wrong in something so simple as passing props.. 
Maybe the createUserProfileDocument function gets called before the displayName gets passed inside that handleSubmit? 
(Got to say I'm not fully confident with async await yet, so that may be the cause combined with hooks)

Thank you in advance for your help on spotting this issue!

Comment: if `console.log(displayName)` shows the correct value before invoking `createUserProfileDocument`, I see no reason for the value of `additionalData` to be undefined. Can you share a screenshot of the log? And because I see `...additionalData` in the commented out code in the function body I suspect the `additionalData`  value needs to be an object, but you are passing just the string value of `displayName` when calling `createUserProfileDocument`.  So if you try to access `additionalData.displayName` obviously it will be `undefined`. Please let me know if i missed something.

Comment: Hi subashMahapatra, first of all thank you for helping me again. I commented out the spreaded additionalData, as in the future I would like to be able to pass more than just a single prop; To do that I would pass an object on SignUp component like this: await createUserProfileDocument(newUser, { displayName, otherProps }); but for now that is not relevant; the displayName is stored inside user as user.displayName and so far that was the only property I had to pass to the createUserProfileDocument function - hope that explains

Comment: If I replace the function call with: await createUserProfileDocument(newUser, "test"), I still get undefined on additionalData.. As you said I see no reasons why it wouldn't pass that prop.. I updated the post adding some screenshots

Comment: If you have already called  `await createUserProfileDocument(newUser, "test")`  and still getting the value of `additionalData` as `undefined`, I would suggest testing the function outside the `handleSubmit` and just mock the `userAuth` object, for example try this and see if the log changes. `useEffect(() => { createUserProfileDocument({uid: 1234}, "test") }, [])`. Don't try to submit or anything, you would see the log immediately when the component mounts, See if `additionalData` is still undefined.

Comment: Good point; I tested and it works on the useEffect; Tried inside the handleSubmit (just before the try and catch) and it works; So I tried moving it inside the try and catch and still works (using the params you gave me ({uid: 1234}, "test"); So I found out that I get the additionalData to be undefined when I replace {uid: 1234} with 'newUser'.. Why would it be doing such behaviour?

Comment: Tried removing the await from { newUser } = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(..) but still get same behaviour

Comment: Another thing I've noticed, return type of function [`createUserWithEmailAndPassword`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createuserwithemailandpassword) is `Promise<UserCredential>` [UserCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#usercredential) and it doesn't contain any property with name `newUser` but it has the property with name `user`.  You should be destructuring the property  `user` instead of `newUser`, `const { user } = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);`.

Comment: YES, that was the reason why I was getting additionalData as undefined! I would give you thousands of thumbsup for catching that, well done and most of all a HUGE thank you for your time on helping me!! p.s. that was quiet weird though

Comment: Yes indeed, I still can't wrap my head around why this strange behavior occurred. I will be posting the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method [`createUserWithEmailAndPassword`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createuserwithemailandpassword) returns a value of type `Promise<UserCredential>` and the value of [`UserCredential`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#usercredential) doesn't have a property name of `newUser`. It contains the user data in the property `user` instead.

**The solution for the issue**

```js
const { user } = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
```

P.S. -
While the code above resolves the issue, I'm still very uncertain why the value of `additionalData` (the second arg) was `undefined` when `createUserProfileDocument` was invoked with the value `newUser` (undefined) as the first argument and `displayName` a string value as the second arg.

If someone knows the reason for this behaviour, please let me know and feel free to edit the answer.